# What is pressure gradient? What is the unit of pressure gradient?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

What is pressure gradient?  What is the unit of pressure gradient?  Is pressure gradient only used in fluid mechanics?  Are differential pressure and pressure gradient the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to think of pressure gradients $\vec{\nabla} P$ is to think of force per unit volume. Dimensionally they are the same [$N m^{-3}$]. The reason you encounter it in fluid mechanics is in the study of *local* dynamics of the fluid, such as the Euler equation, or more generally the Navier Stokes equation. A pressure gradient tells you (look at Euler equation) the directional derivative of the fluid's velocity or how a fluid element moves from higher to lower pressure - this is Newton's law for fluids. A pressure difference is not exactly the same as a pressure gradient but they are related. An elemental pressure change along an infinitesimal line element $\vec{dl}$ is
$$ dP = \vec{\nabla}P \cdot \vec{dl}$$
You can integrate but this is trivial by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

You will also encounter pressure gradients and forces per unit volume in the context of Magnetohydrodynamics (fluid mechanics + Maxwell's equations), Plasma physics and hence also in Astrophysics.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure is measured usually in units called Pascal (other places $torr$, atmosphere $atm$ or $mm Hg$ or $psi$ or $N/m^2$ etc). Pressure gradient simply means a *rate of change in pressure* through a given region. Differential pressure is the difference between applied pressures at two points and is measured in psi or Newton/m.

You can consider the pressure gradient as the "force driving flow" where

$F = \Delta P/R$

and clearly pressure gradient will have units of Pa/m (note this is in one dimension and in this case we are using Pascal) which is not the same as just pressure.

The pressure gradient does not apply to fluids only.
For example, the earth's atmosphere (a mixed gas), the pressure gradient can be expressed as an exponentially decaying $function$.
Above sea level (and at low altitudes), the pressure decreases by about 1200 Pa for every 100 metres or 12 Pa/m.

Comment: A pressure gradient is not a pressure difference. It is the rate of change of pressure in space. ($dP/dx$ in one dimension.) Its SI units are pascals *per meter*.

Comment: @Drjh in paragraph 1 did you mean newton per square metre?

Comment: *Since a pressure gradient is a measure of pressure through a region, it will have the same units as pressure.* This is still wrong, and contradicts what you said after your edit. Clearly a pascal is not the same unit as a pascal per meter.

Comment: sorry - missed a "not" obviously.

Comment: @G.Smith If you see typos please feel free to edit. Thanks.

Comment: What is a *tor*?

Comment: Instead of saying "Thanks" you can better upvote the comment. :-)

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Can it be said that the pressure gradient is the ratio of the pressure difference to the distance?

Comment: @enbin If the pressure is varying linearly in the x, y, and z directions (which means it varies linearly in every direction), yes. If not, you'll have to take the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure gradient is a vector which points in the direction of maximal pressure at a point.

> It is calculated as - $$\vec{\nabla}P = \frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{x}}\hat{x} + \frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{y}}\hat{y} + \frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{z}}\hat{z}$$
> It has the units of $Pascal/m$ i.e. if you move 1 m in the direction of pressure gradient the pressure will increase by ${\nabla}P$ Pascal.

Pressure gradient is also used in analysing gravitational pressure.